# JavaScript is not being passed through proxy

Tags: javascript, apache, proxy

I don't seem to understand something about proxying and JavaScript. I have searched several posts, but I am none the wiser...

I have a CentOS (6.4) server that functions as a proxy for another server (ARMv7). Both run Apache; the first one is version 2.2.15, the second one is version 2.2.22.

The proxy config on the first server is as follows:

```
ProxyPass /PV/    http://192.168.0.30/electricity/
```

When calling http://mysite.bla.xxx/PV/, I do get (part of) the index.html file served that is on the second server.
However, the index.html file starts with this:

```
<html>
  <head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/javascript/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  ......
```

And here's where it goes wrong... When I examine the error-log on the proxyserver, I see:

> File does not exist: /var/www/html/javascript, referer: http://mysite.bla.xxx/PV/

And of course, this file/directory does not exist.

I'm guessing that the second `<script>` tag is the culprit, because it wants to find something at /javascript locally on the first server that doesn't exist.

Am I right? If so, how can I get Apache on the proxying server to serve the scripts included in index.html on the second server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop the first slash from the js's URL.

Not `<script src="/javascript/jquery/jquery.js">`

but `<script src="javascript/jquery/jquery.js">`

Paths beginning with a slash will be assumed to reside in root. Thus your link points to `http://mysite.bla.xxx/javascript/jquery/jquery.js`

Comment: Wow, that was fast! Thanks Thykka, but that is not the complete solution...The error on the proxyserver has gone, but now I get a new entry in the errorlog of the second server, saying `GET /PV/javascript/jquery/jquery.js HTTP/1.1 404` So, still a 404, but now on the second server. And, no, there is no directory javascript containing jquery. Could it be that https in the first line is spoiling everything ? (At the moment I'm behind a company firewall/proxy, which usually allows https sites) ?

Comment: AFAIK the link `http://mysite.bla.xxx/PV/javascript/jquery/jquery.js` *should* lead to `http://192.168.0.30/electricity/javascript/jquery/jquery.js`, instead of `http://192.168.0.30/PV/javascript/jquery/jquery.js`... Am I missing something?

Comment: That looks like the address in the GET is starting with a forward slash (same as the accepted answer).